# Conditions on $f(t)$ so that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \operatorname{sinc}(t-a) \operatorname{sinc}(t-b) dt$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let us consider
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \operatorname{sinc}(t-a) \operatorname{sinc}(t-b) dt \ \ \ \ (*)$$
for $a,b\in \mathbb R$. If $f\in L^1(-\infty,\infty)$ the integral converges:
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \operatorname{sinc}(t-a) \operatorname{sinc}(t-b) dt\right|\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|f(t)\right| dt$$
But I think this is a too strong condition. What are the conditions to be imposed on $f(t)$ so that (*) converges?

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: sinc=sin right ?

Comment: @HKLee, $\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\frac{\sin \pi t}{\pi t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\text{sinc}(t)| \le 1/(\pi |t|)$, it suffices to have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\dfrac{|f(x)|\; dx}{1+x^2} < \infty$$

Comment: Thanks @Robert Israel, but I don't understand why $1+x^2$ as denominator.

Comment: The $1$ is included to avoid a singularity at $x=0$.  The point is that this has essentially the same behaviour as $x \to \pm\infty$ as $\text{sinc}(t-a) \text{sinc}(t-b)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @Robert!